# Hoy to add Locale to path using React js and i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, i18next

I am using React Js and i18next to try to build an app with multiple Language

I want to generate the Local inside my URL, the Problem that the Prefix would be added multiple times in the URL!

Here is my configuration:

**i18n.js**

```
i18n
// i18next-http-backend
// loads translations from your server
// https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
.use(Backend)
// detect user language
// learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
.use(LanguageDetector)
// pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
.use(initReactI18next)
// init i18next
// for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
.init({
    debug: true,
    supportedLngs: ['de','en','fr'],
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    whitelist: ['de','en','fr'],
    detection: {
        order: ['path','cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'sessionStorage','subdomain'],
        caches: ['cookie'],
        lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
        checkWhitelist: true
    },
    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
        // format: (value, format, lng) => { // legacy usage
        //   if (value instanceof Date) {
        //     return DateTime.fromJSDate(value).setLocale(lng).toLocaleString(DateTime[format])
        //   }
        //   return value;
        // }
    },
    backend: {
        loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
    }
});
```

**Routing:**

```
function App() {
const baseRouteUrl = "/:locale(en|de|fr)?";

return (
    //@todo add baseurl
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
        <BrowserRouter >
            <Suspense fallback={<p>...Loading</p>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={baseRouteUrl + "/"} component={Home} />
                    <Route path={baseRouteUrl + "/about"} component={About} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </I18nextProvider>

    );
  }
```

**Navigation:**

```
const Navigation = () => {
const baseUrl = cookies.get('i18next');
return (
    
        <Link to={baseUrl + "/"}> Home </Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to={baseUrl + "/about/"}>About </Link>
  
  );
};
```

the URL would be:

**http://localhost:3000/en/about/**

**http://localhost:3000/en/de/about/**

Thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of the cookie?

Does it help if you use the [resolvedLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage) value instead?

```
<Link to={i18n.resolvedLanguage + "/about/"}>About </Link>
```

btw: you can remove the whitelist option, whitelist was renamed to supportedLngs

Comment: Thanks, @adrai, I have two other problems that I really couldn't find how to manage that, i have a dropdown with languages it's working fine i just want to make the entry Point (URL) (http://localhost:3000/en) contain the local prefix and when i change the Dropdown that local in the URL would be change :( Should i create an other question for that ? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes I would suggest you create a new question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71735783/set-entry-url-with-prefix-using-reactjs-and-i18next